# android layout issue when using sliding menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following main activity and I want to use the sliding menu in my activity

The ExampleActivity code is:

```
package com.example.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity;
public class ExampleActivity extends SlidingActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // set the content view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.sliding_menu);

        // configure the SlidingMenu
        getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        getSlidingMenu().setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);
    }
}
```

My layout file sliding_menu.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slidingmenumain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    sliding:touchModeAbove="margin"
    sliding:behindOffset="@dimen/0"
    sliding:behindWidth="@dimen/0"
    sliding:behindScrollScale="@dimen/0.25f"
    sliding:fadeEnabled="true"
    sliding:fadeDegree="1.0f"
    sliding:selectorEnabled="true"

    />
```

I am totally new to android I want to ask you is the layout file has anything wrong? because I got an error message

> unbound prefix

I think I should change the android after xmlns with sliding but If I did it still giving me the same error?

Comment: The answer below is correct but you can also create sliding menu using  code in activity instead of XML. Check out its official GitHub repo

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this in your layout xml file :-
`xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
for more Information please take a look at [How to use custom attributes with View](http://droid-blog.net/2012/04/24/how-to-add-attributes-to-your-custom-view/)

Comment: I try this but same error still showing. How I could use xmlns for both android and sliding should not I use two of them ? I mean xmlns:android and xmlns:sliding ?

Comment: I add this line to my main layout of my main activity and remove all the similar in my sliding_menu layout but I still got the error?

Comment: will you update your question with updated code.. so i ll see what is problem..?